# Show that rank of ring of integers is at least rank of extension.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose I have an extensoin $K/\mathbb{Q}$. Let $\mathcal{O}_k$ be the ring of integers in $K$. I have shown that we have an isomorphism $K\cong\mathbb{Q}^n$ via a bilinear form $\langle f,f'\rangle=Tr_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(ff')$, where $f,f'\in K$. Specifically, $f$ maps to $(\langle f,\lambda_1\rangle,...,\langle f,\lambda_n\rangle)$, where the $\lambda_i$ form a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis of $K$ and $\lambda_i\in\mathcal{O}_K$.

Hence (using properties of the trace), I have an embedding, as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, of $\mathcal{O}_k\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}^n$. Thus, $\mathcal{O}_k$ is finitely generated, and I can show that the rank of $\mathcal{O}_k\leq n$.

But to show rank of $\mathcal{O}_k\geq n$, I am a little lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are elements $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ of $K$ which are linearly independent
over $\Bbb Q$. There are positive integers $m_1,\ldots,m_n$ for which $m_1\alpha_1,
\ldots,m_n\alpha_n\in\mathcal O_K$. Then $m_1\alpha_1,\ldots,m_n\alpha_n$
are still linearly independent over $\Bbb Q$ and so the rank of $\mathcal O_K$
must be at least $n$.

Comment: Ah, so then as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, $\mathcal{O}_K$ also has rank at least $n$. Thanks!